# Sync core data database/ .sqlite file to Dropbox

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, dropbox

I'm trying to sync/upload my core data database/.sqlite file to dropbox. 
once my user logs in, i have a button to upload the file:

```
-(IBAction)sync{

NSString *localPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cache" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSString *filename = @"cache.db";
NSString *destDir = @"/";
[self.restClient uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
}
```

But the problem here is: I dont know the name of my .sqlite data base, I've looked under :

`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<SDK>/Applications/<UUID>/Documents/bc.db`

//I have looked into every file also and i couldnt find a `.sqlite` file.

But i cannot find any file called:`app name.sqlite` I can only find `cache.db` so, im not sure what im supposed to do from here? Can i upload the cache.db file? or is there another file that is `app name.sqlite`? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using Core Data with SQLite, or just SQLite?  There is a big difference.

Comment: im using core data with sqlite! @codafi

Comment: Great, then this won't work.  Core Data uses a complicated series of proprietary file formats that are spread around in the directory that the database resides.  You can sync the container to iCloud the recommended way, but I don't believe you can do much else that doesn't [involve reinventing the wheel](http://timisted.github.com/TICoreDataSync/).  What I'm trying to say is, cache.db doesn't exist, and it never will!

Comment: okay, i understand. But i have read about other developers doing what im trying to do. I just need to upload my sqlite file. And im not sure what its called! @codafi

Comment: and by sync the `conatiner`.. what exactly does that mean? THanks for the help!

Comment: Perhaps you're not quite getting what I'm saying: There is no SQLite database file that is user or developer manipulateable when you have a Core Data store.  Instead, you get a container that has all the necessary Core Data files and associated mess.  The link in the earlier comment is a working implementation of what you're trying to do, I recommend you take a look at it instead of going out and reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @CodaFi, actually there is a SQLite file, if you're using the SQLite store. It's a single file unless you're using "Allows External Storage", in which case binary attributes go outside the file. It's not intended to be accessed directly but it's possible to do so-- for example, using "Core Data Editor" (available in the Mac app store). You're right about syncing though-- this isn't how to do it.

Comment: @codafi i really do appreciate your help, as well as yours Tom Harrington

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQLite file is wherever you created it. There's no mystery-- you have to tell Core Data where you want the file, and it goes where you say it should go.

If you used one of Apple's project templates you probably have a line in your app delegate class (in the `persistentStoreCoordinator` method) that looks like

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.sqlite"];
```

That's where it is, and that's how you should find the file path in your app.

That **might** be everything. If you're not using binary attributes with "Allows External Storage" checked, it's the entire data store. If you **are** using those, there's a parallel, hidden directory whose name is undocumented that contains the external binaries.

Copying the data store to Dropbox is not likely to be useful. You cannot sync your data store from one device to another this way-- data corruption is virtually guaranteed.

Comment: thanks for the answer, and what would be a better way to sync my core data to drop box?

Comment: i was trying to get the sqlite file from my main bundle, when in fact it was in the documents directory! silly noob mistake..

Comment: If you want to sync Core Data via Dropbox, TICoreDataSync (mentioned by CodaFi) is the only real option right now. You might also consider third party options like WasabiSync or Simperium.

Comment: @TomHarrington , Hi Tom, Could you please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287039/get-sqlite-files-from-core-data-applicationwhich-is-crashing-on-launch-instal question? It will be very helpful if you can tell me how should I proceed to solve my problem.