# Access or download .csv file from dropbox using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, csv, dropbox

I'm trying to download or access a .csv file from dropbox. [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdo29dx4baxc18a/export.csv?dl=0) is the link I need to access.

I did some research, and I came up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915168/sync-core-data-database-sqlite-file-to-dropbox), but I can't insert a url or anything.

I'm a beginner, so please don't be too harsh on me.

Answer (score 0):

The type of file is inconsequential in this case -- you just need to download the data from a URL.

First of all, the url should end with `dl=1` instead of `dl=0`, which will trigger a download rather than going to the landing page.

Secondly, you need to get the data.  There are quite a few potential methods that you can use for that in Obj-C, but the easiest and perhaps most common is to just do something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:"https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdo29dx4baxc18a/export.csv?dl=1"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Then, the variable `data` contains the downloaded information.  If you need to write that to a file, that's easy to do (search here on SO for writing NSData to a file), or if you just need the data in memory, you're good to go.

Alternately, Dropbox has an Objective-C SDK that you can use for more Dropbox-specific tasks (especially if it turns out later you need to access private documents, etc).  See this link: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/ios

Comment: Can I convert the data to a string like this? NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Should be able to (make sure to double check your encoding).  Or, go direct, with something like: `NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];`